# Replacement for the phrase "Online Presence"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a CV. I have a section which I've currently named "Online Presence" in which I give details of my online accounts – Twitter, LinkedIn, GitHub, Stack Exchange, etc.

But the phrase "Online Presence" seems a little awkward and uncomfortable – is there any better phrase to use instead?

Comment: "Online presence" is certainly [an established term](http://www.brighton.ac.uk/careers/cvs-and-interviews/your-online-presence/) for what you describe. Why is it awkward?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was just feeling little uncomfortable with the phrase. Since, it's _an establish term_, I'll use it. However, any alternatives for that phrase?

Answer (score 0):

I think another accepted term is [*Social media footprint.*](https://www.google.com/#q=social+media+footprint)

Comment: But perhaps a little narrower in scope - that would cover facebook, twitter, linked in and possibly a blog, but not a traditional website.

Comment: Sure, but the OP didn't mention a website. He or she could go with [digital footprint](https://www.google.com/#q=digital+footprint) too.

Comment: True enough - the conclusion I drew from the OP's phrase and short list of examples was broader than yours - with your *digital footprint* alternative you cover both senses though (maybe it should be in your answer as well).  They might be widely accepted phrases (and therefore get my vote), but personally I don't like them: A footprint is an impression you leave behind, while generally social media, especially if it's [I want to say they're] going on a CV, would be maintained - as a *presence* implies better than a *footprint*.

Comment: @JLG Thanks for the response, actually I need to have accounts like `github`, `stackexchange`. Any ideas?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect JLG's given you *digital footprint*, there's also *online footprint*.